# Changing the content of HTTP headers for some requests only - Angular2

Tags: angular, http, http-headers, http-post

In my Angular2 app, I have added a `CustomRequestOptions` class extending `BaseRequestOptions` to add some headers to each and every request I send to the server. One major purpose of having that is setting the Authorization header.

```
import { Http, Response, Headers, BaseRequestOptions, RequestOptions, RequestOptionsArgs } from '@angular/http';
import { Globals } from '../globals/globals';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class CustomRequestOptions extends BaseRequestOptions {
    constructor(private _globals: Globals) {
        super();
        this.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        this.headers.set('X-Requested-By', 'Angular 2');
    }

    merge(options?: RequestOptionsArgs): RequestOptions {
       var newOptions = super.merge(options);
       let hdr = this._globals.getAuthorization();
       newOptions.headers.set("Authorization", hdr);
       console.log("content TYPE = "+this.headers.get("Content-Type"));
       console.log("ACCepT = "+this.headers.get("Accept"));

       return newOptions;
    }

}
```

This works perfectly fine for my requirements.

Now I have come across a need to upload a photo to the server. Following is how I am trying to do that.

```
savePhoto(photoToSave: File) {

    let formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('uploadFile', photoToSave, photoToSave.name);

    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    let savedPath = this._http
        .post(this._endpointUrl + "tender/save-new/save-photo", formData, options)
        .map(
        res => {
            return res.json();
        }
        )
        .catch(handleError);

    return savedPath;

}
```

As you can see, I need to change the `Content-Type` header to `multipart/form-data`. But, the Custom Request options class always reset it to `application/json` whenever the request goes through it.

How can I do this? is there any way that I can set my custom headers('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data') after the `CustomRequestOptions` class is called?

Answer (score 0):

In your CustomRequestOptions constructor, you are calling `super()` which set the headers you provided in savePhoto, then overriding it with `this.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');`.

To go around this scenario, I suggest creating an instance of RequestOptions first then override the headers after. As shown below. (Disclaimer, I have not tested this code)

```
savePhoto(photoToSave: File) {

    let formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('uploadFile', photoToSave, photoToSave.name);

    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    let options = new RequestOptions();
    options.headers = headers;
    ...
}
```

Also, check if you can override individual header (if you want to retain the value `'X-Requested-By', 'Angular 2'`)

Finally, check if `super()` can be moved to the last line of the constructor (i highly doubt it) so that you will not change your `savePhoto()` implementation.

Comment: constructor is called only once when the the class is initialized.  As I know, merge is the method which is called everytime a request is made